# Determine if character has case in JAVA

Tags: java, android, string

In JAVA (Android), I'm trying to determine in a String, if each character has a equivalent in upper or lower case.

My goal is not to lower or upper the case, but to know if it's possible.

For example this function would return true for : 'e' 'é' 'i' 'l' 'L' 'O' 'P'
and false for emojis or chinese characters.

Is there any function that can do this?

EDIT : To be more clear, the function was supposed to take a character for argument, not a String and return false if the character had no uppercase or lowercase version.

Comment: Compare the uppercased version to the lowercased version, see if they are different (but beware of locale issues).

Comment: "determine ... if each character has a equivalent in upper or lower case" -- do you care whether the upper/lowercase equivalent is a *different character* from the original? Also, are you trying to take locale (e.g. Turkish) into account? If so, you should use `String` rather than `Character` methods. Also, what do you want the result to be for TitleCase characters?

Comment: Okay my question is badly asked the function will not be applied to the string, but to each character of the string, for your example, TitleCase, it will give true for each letter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
boolean validate(char c){
    return Character.isUpperCase(c) || Character.isLowerCase(c);
}
```

This will return `true` iff it is a Letter in uppercase or lower case only. Otherwise it'll return false.

Comment: Now updated the answer. Can you take a look at it? @SotiriosDelimanolis

Comment: I think I'm going to validate that, it does exactly what I need in only one statement. Tested for arabic characters (returns false as expected), emojis (false) chinese (false) and every character with an accent that I tested (true) .
It also returns false for special caracters like @ ' [ (as expected)

Comment: @liltof This returns incorrect results for TitleCase characters: They're neither uppercase nor lowercase, but they do have an uppercase and a lowercase equivalent. But maybe the question didn't say quite what you meant.

Comment: You don't understand, the goal is to check for EACH character of the string, not the whole string so for TitleCase, I need the result for T, i, t, l, e, C, a, s, AND e :D I edited the question to be more clear

Comment: @liltof see http://unicode.org/faq/casemap_charprop.html#4. Some *single characters*, like ǈ (`\u01c8`), are actually in titlecase. (Thank you for editing to question to be clearer -- always appreciated!)

Comment: For this character ( ǈ ) this also returns false! it's exactly what I wanted :D

Comment: @liltof Yes it returns false, but that's incorrect according to your question: "trying to determine ... if each character has a equivalent in upper or lower case". ǈ has both. Maybe your question needs to be tweaked. Why do you want it to return false for ǈ?

Comment: No, this character has no upper or lower case, it has --only-- the title case (which I don't care about)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147184/discussion-between-liltof-and-larsh).

Comment: @liltof Why do you say it has no upper or lower case? The uppercase equivalent is U+01C7, and the lowercase equivalent is U+01C9 (see http://unicode.scarfboy.com/?s=U%2b01C8).

Answer (score 1):

For a simple method, there's Character.isLowerCase.  But you actually need to be careful-  it depends on language.  Some languages may have a lower case 'é' but no uppercase.  Or like the turkish "I" may have a different lower case version than other languages.

To work around that, I'd use something like `Character.isLetter(myChar) && String.valueOf(myChar).toLowerCase().equals(String.valueOf(myChar))`.  Remember to use the version of toLowerCase that takes a Locale as parameter if not comparing in the default Locale.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the character is either a lowercase letter or an uppercase letter:

```
Character.isLowerCase(ch) != Character.isUpperCase(ch)
```

Alternatively, you can compare the lower and uppercased forms of the character:

```
Character.toLowerCase(ch) == Character.toUpperCase(ch)
```

However, you need to be careful about locale (there is one letter in Turkish where I think the lower and uppercase forms are the same).

Comment: Why `!=` in the first expression, instead of `||`? The equivalence of `!=` to `||` here (and you describe the expression in terms of 'or') relies on the assumption that no character is ever both upper and lowercase ... which is probably true but obscure. Why not just use `||`?

Answer (score 1):

The requirements are still not entirely specified (do you care whether the upper/lowercase equivalent is a *different character* from the original?), but my most straightforward interpretation of the question is:

> For each character `ch` in a given string, is it true that either `toUpperCase(ch)` yields an uppercase character, or that `toLowerCase(ch)` yields a lowercase character?

I phrase it that way because [`Character.toUpperCase()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toUpperCase(int)) returns "the uppercase equivalent of the character, if any; otherwise, the character itself".
The [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase()) for `String.toUppercase()` doesn't mention what happens if there is no uppercase equivalent for some characters, but I think we can assume it returns those characters unchanged, as does `Character.toUpperCase()`.

So a straightforward implementation of that condition would be to test

```
    Character.isUpperCase(s.toUpperCase().charAt(0)) ||
    Character.isLowerCase(s.toLowerCase().charAt(0));
```

for each character as a String.

I'm using the `String` rather than `Character` case conversion functions here, in order to take advantage of locale-sensitive mapping. Not only that, but regardless of locale, there are characters that cannot be converted to uppercase by `Character.toUpperCase()` because their uppercase equivalent is more than one character! For example, we would get incorrect results for \u00df 'ß' (see [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase(java.util.Locale)) for details).

```
public class TestUpper {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String test = "\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645 World \u00df\u01c8eéilLOP\u76f4!";

        for (Character ch : test.toCharArray()) {
            System.out.format("'%c' (U+%04x): hasCase()=%b%n", ch, (int)ch, hasCase(ch));
        }
    }

    static boolean hasCase(Character ch) {
        String s = ch.toString();
        // Does the character s have an uppercase or a lowercase equivalent?
        return Character.isUpperCase(s.toUpperCase().charAt(0)) ||
             Character.isLowerCase(s.toLowerCase().charAt(0));
    }
}
```

And the results:

```
'س' (U+0633): hasCase()=false
'ل' (U+0644): hasCase()=false
'ا' (U+0627): hasCase()=false
'م' (U+0645): hasCase()=false
' ' (U+0020): hasCase()=false
'W' (U+0057): hasCase()=true
'o' (U+006f): hasCase()=true
'r' (U+0072): hasCase()=true
'l' (U+006c): hasCase()=true
'd' (U+0064): hasCase()=true
' ' (U+0020): hasCase()=false
'ß' (U+00df): hasCase()=true
'ǈ' (U+01c8): hasCase()=true
'e' (U+0065): hasCase()=true
'é' (U+00e9): hasCase()=true
'i' (U+0069): hasCase()=true
'l' (U+006c): hasCase()=true
'L' (U+004c): hasCase()=true
'O' (U+004f): hasCase()=true
'P' (U+0050): hasCase()=true
'直' (U+76f4): hasCase()=false
'!' (U+0021): hasCase()=false
```

These test cases include Arabic letters and a Chinese character (which are `isLetter()`, but have no upper/lowercase equivalents), the requested test letters, space and punctuation, and a titlecase letter.

The results are correct according to the criteria currently stated in the question. However, the OP has said in comments that he wants the function to return `false` for titlecase characters, such as U+01c8, whereas the above code returns `true` because they have uppercase and lowercase equivalents (U+01c7 and U+01c9). But the OP's statement seems to be based on the mistaken impression that titlecase letters do *not* have uppercase and lowercase equivalents. Ongoing discussion has not yet resolved the confusion.

Disclaimer: This answer doesn't attempt to take into account supplementary or surrogate code points.

Answer (score -1):

Two strings uppercase and lowercase not matching does not necessarily mean the string is valid. `true1` will not equal `TRUE1` but fails the test case. You need to check each individual character. This is a rough cut, you'll probably have to do something fancy for emojis and Chinese characters.

```
public static boolean isAllCase(String value) {
    String upper = value.toUpperCase();
    String lower = value.toLowerCase();

    if(upper.length() != lower.length())
        return false;

    for(int i = 0; i < upper.length(); i++) {
        if(upper.charAt(i) == lower.charAt(i))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Carefull: Calling the toUpperCase and toLowerCase methods of the String class might actually change the length of the string so that upper and lowercase versions have different length. calling your method with `isAllCase("ß")` will therefor lead to a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException. I would recommend doing the upper/lowercase conversion of the String inside the loop with the Character class (Character.toUpperCase).

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS Would a length check work in this case?

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS: I don't see how doing the upper/lowercase conversion with `Character.toUpperCase` would help, since the doc says this method can't handle 1:M mappings (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toUpperCase(int)).

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS: Why do you say the Character class would give `true`? When I tested `Character.toUpperCase('\u00df')` it returned \u00df (consistent with the docs), which results in a return of `false`: there is not an uppercase version. The debate over whether \u1e9e is an acceptable uppercase version of ß is interesting, but the bottom line for the OP is whether the `Character.toUpperCase()` can be relied on to answer the question correctly, and in this case it demonstrably can't.

Comment: The uppercase version is '\u1E9E'. I did a quick test with  Character.toLowerCase('\u1E9E') to see if the Character class can handle that and it correctly converts to lower case. I assumed that the methods are symmetric and that if conversion to lowercase works then toUpperCase would also work. Obviously I was wrong and the answer is f**k all the toLowerCase/toUpperCase methods and use Character.isLowerCase/Character.isUpperCase as detailed in the other answers. (As that one will actually tell you that there is a lower and uppercase version of ß. for real this time ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
 public boolean hasEquivalentCase(char ch) { 
    return (Character.isLowerCase(ch)) || Character.isUpperCase(ch)
  }
```

Comment: Why the down vote ? this actually seems good no ? if the character is not upper and not lowercase it means that it cannot be converted to upper or lowercase no?

Comment: Yeah. It should work that way. Wonder why the downvote.

Comment: It's duplicate of my answer I think.

Comment: I didn't downvote it (yet) but one reason for a downvote would be the use of undefined variable `i`. @liltof "if the character is not upper and not lowercase it means that it cannot be converted to upper or lowercase" This is incorrect. TitleCase characters, for example.

Comment: Why you say it's incorrect? I've tested, and I think I will validate this answer (the first one)! It returns true for e é a O A and false for smileys, emojis arabic caracters and chinese ones

Comment: Notwithstanding technical accuracy, answers which only include code with no explanation are often downvoted; you could improve it by describing how your code snippet works to solve the issue.

Comment: Musa, where is the variable `s` defined? Doesn't `charAt()` take an integer rather than a character argument? Have you tried testing your code?

Answer (score -2):

```
public boolean validate(char value){
    if( (value >= 'a' && value <= 'z') || (value >= 'A' && 
       value <= 'Z')
          return true;
    return false;
}
```

this for each caracter to your String.

```
public boolean All( String cad ){
    for( int i = 0; i < cad.lenght() ; i++ ){
       if( !validate(cad.charAt(i)) ){
           #the letter has not upper or lower
           return false; 
       }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: @Fabian: There are more letters than a-Z that can have upper and lower cases. In the question the asker specifically gave the example of  'é'